# Azure Search Spell mistake handling

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, azure-cognitive-search

My application is in MVC and I have a search text box based on azure index, its working fine however I have a scenario where in if I enter **"chres Harris"** instead of **"chris Harris"** it should return result **"chris Harris"** but it returns different result like "bob Harris" and then **"chris harris",** I want the results to be nearabout the same even if there is a spell mistake, please help will any index scoring profile, parameter boost or something useful ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what you have tried, e.g. how is the text box perfoming its lookup, what is the data set that it is looking up against?

Comment: well its a search text box where in user can search, indexes are created and binded with azure sql data via .net, I have added suggestor as well however I need to suffice above requirement and I can see there is a option to add analyzers what it is for any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

As of now there are two ways you can handle spelling mistakes in Azure Search.

1. Use fuzzy queries with [Lucene query language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt589323.aspx#bkmk_fuzzy). You can boost relevance of exact matches over fuzzy matches for example, search=term^2 OR term~2.
2. If you deal with names of things, like in your example, configure your index to support [phonetic search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search/). Different boosting options to influence relevance are described in the article.

Let me know if none of them don't works for you.

Comment: Thanks Yahnoosh for replying, could you please help to implement the phonetic search via .net.

Comment: This is a preview feature. It's not exposed in the SDK yet. I will let you know once it is.

Comment: Hi yahnoosh, I tried the phonetic search example however it didn't work for me, do I need to do anything apart from creating index with analyzer phonetic ?

Comment: I'd need more details to understand why it didn't work. Feel free to reach out directly at jlembicz at microsfot.com with your index definition, sample data, and queries that didn't return any results

Comment: Hi Yahnoosh,
I mailed you could you please check and reply !

Comment: Yahnoosh, did you receive my mail ?